# easiest way to set boolean admin attribute to users in the database? (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite

I was trying to get Active Admin to work but unfortunately I may have to do this manually.

I want to set user 1 to be the admin. The user model does not have the :admin attribute listed.

It has

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation
```

Is there a way I can go into the database and just change the admin value of user 1?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do it from the console quickly:

```
rails console
u = User.find(1) # .first if it's not really id => 1, but the first record
u.admin = true
u.save
```

That will do it, but it's not repeatable, which I don't like.  But for a one time fix it'll be ok.

Comment: Do you know what I'm getting error in console when trying to save? ->>> irb(main):003:0> u.save
  ←[1m←[35m (0.0ms)←[0m  begin transaction
  ←[1m←[36mUser Exists (0.0ms)←[0m  ←[1mSELECT 1 FROM "users" WHERE (LOWER("user
s"."email") = LOWER('user1@example.com') AND "users"."id" != 1) LIMIT 1←[0m
  ←[1m←[35m (0.0ms)←[0m  rollback transaction
=> false

Comment: There's not enough information to determine what the issue is.  It's saying the user already exists, but the query is looking for the first user NOT set to id == 1...  You might have to try `u.save(:validate => false)`

Answer (score 0):

quick and easy way to read [Chapter 9.4.1 - Administrative users](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users#sec-administrative_users) from Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial